# Open form with menu item in the same Window

Tags: c#, forms, menustrip

i'm new in the blog, i have a problem with c# programming. 
I'll create a Menustrip but when i click on an Item with the form show event it open in one other form.

```
private void passwordToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GesPass gesPass = new GesPass();
            gesPass.Show();
        }
```

Is there a way to open the new form in the parent window?

Comment: Is this an MDI application?  We need more information here to help you.

Comment: Sorry i'm new about this, it will be a MDI Application but i don't now how can do this

Comment: Try using`this. Controls. Add (gesPass) ` before showing the form.

Comment: also read up on what the following 2 things are when doing MDI application `Parent` and `Owner` there are lots of awesome free tutorials on this particular subject `MDI` online as well

Comment: If the parent form has IsMdiContainer = true, then you would have to add the line `gesPass.MdiParent = this;` before the Show(); line.

Comment: Solved thanks LarsTech

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the MdiParent property to associate the child form to the MDI parent container:

```
GesPass gesPass = new GesPass();
gesPass.MdiParent = this;
gesPass.Show();
```